# How to draw a leaf using Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, drawing

I am trying to draw the following leaf<sup>1</sup> using inkscape:

[image: the leaf]

More precisely I would like to get the outer shape of the leaf. I have tried to get it using the intersection of two circles:

[image: circle intersection]

But the shape is clearly different from the first image.

Could you please explain how can I proceed to reproduce that leaf?

Thank you

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Image taken from [this webpage](https://www.iconspng.com/image/61735/leaf-with-venation-two-color)</sub>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Intersection of 2 circles is ok. It's done in the middle of the next image:

[image]

In the right there's used the node tool. The top node is dragged upwards and it's handles are turned for sharper angle.

Intersection converts circles to a Bezier curve (=path). Modifying its nodes, node handles, removing nodes and inserting more of them is just the basic skill in Inkscape and other vector drawing programs. It's as important as drawing your own curves with the Bezier curve tool (=also known as "the pen"). Do not skip practicing those skills.

With the pen you can draw a curve which divides your leaf. In the next image only a 2 click straight line is added (red) It could as well be a curved path:

[image]

In the middle the leaf is divided with the line by applying Path > Division. In the right the halves are colored differently.

I guess that soon after practicing a while with the pen you see that it gives to you a good freedom to draw solid looking shapes directly. You'll start to draw shapes that your job needs and use circles only, when circular forms or the geometric facts of circles really are needed. For example one draws the next 2 part leaf with the pen straight in the fly in a minute including possibly a fast fix of a border curvature with the node tool and coloring:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't quite understand how to get that shape on the right.

Comment: I selected the node tool into use. I clicked the top corner and dragged it upwards. The handles are stretched a little longer and the balls at their ends are moved a little closer to the leaf. Search for path editing tutorials and work through a few of them! It pays off with 10000% interest.

Answer (score 8):

Here are a couple of techniques

1. Make an ellipse (not a circle), and rotate it
2. Duplicate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and reflect the ellipse horizontally <kbd>H</kbd>
3. Hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as you click and drag the duplicate away so that they overlap in a leaf shape.
4. Select both ellipses and do *Path > Intersection* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>

[image]

If you need two separate halves, you could use a rectangle to do the Intersection instead, then duplicate and reflect the piece, and move into position using snapping.

[image]

Comment: Great technique, thank you! btw I miss your videos on your Youtube channel.

Comment: @OK-Validation - Thanks. I should make some new ones probably, just never seem to have the time - spend too much time here!

Comment: @OK-Validation BTW if you are looking for really good Inkscape tutorials I can highly recommend the youtube channel "Logos by Nick"

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!